# How to make SybaseIQ case insensitive?

Tags: case-insensitive, sap-iq

I created my DB(SYbaseIQ 16.X) with Case IGNORE feature, but it's failing for all select due to case sensitivity. I tried ALTER DATABASE command, but it doesn't have any such option.

How can I revert my DB to case IGNORE setting, and also to check what are the configurations of my DB?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change it. You need to create a brand new database using the `iqinit` utility with the `-c` switch (for case-sensitivity). Then you'll need to use an external tool to dump the schema of your original database and then use the IQ "extract" command to get the data. Once you have those, use `dbisql` to create the new schema and import the data into the new database.